# Geometric method to calculate $\tanh(\cosh^{-1}(x))$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-functions

How to calculate $\tanh(\cosh^{-1}(x))$?

And is there a similar method as when calculating: $\tan(\cos^{-1}(x))$?
When calculating $\tan(\cos^{-1}(x))$ I would draw a right-triangle like this:

[image]

Such that $\tan(\cos^{-1}(x))=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

QUESTION: Is there a similar geometric method available to calculate $\tanh(\cosh^{-1}(x))$?

Comment: $\cosh(y)=x$ means that $\sinh(y)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $\tanh\left(\cosh^{-1}(x)\right)=\tanh(y)=\frac{\sinh(y)}{\cosh(y)}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$.

Comment: read up on hyperbolas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Answer (score 1):

Using the hyperbolic function identity $1+\sinh^2 u = \cosh^2 u$, draw a right triangle with one leg equal to $1$ and the hypoteneuse equal to $x=\cosh u$.  Then $\tanh u$ is the ratio of the other leg to the hypoteneuse.